# How to make a container view size itself by the components inside it in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a container view to a `UIViewController` in my storyboard that is managed by a separate `UIViewController`. This container view needs to have a height associated with it in order to lay out the items correctly. However, the height of this container view is dynamic, because it contains a `UITextView` among other items. Before, when I didn't use a container view, auto layout calculated the height of the items for me. Now I've moved everything to a container view it seems like this isn't possible. Am I going to have to manually calculate the height of my container view and apply it to a constraint, or is there a way to let auto layout deal with it?

Comment: Just set `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` inside the view controller that is the "child".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do this, but you need a little bit of code.

When a `UIViewController` is embedded in a container view, its "root view" has its `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to true, and its frame is automatically set to the bounds of the container view.

If your embedded VC has constraints set to properly resize itself, you can disable `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on its root view when it is loaded.

As an example, suppose we have this layout, and the label in the "content VC" will have a variable number of lines:

[image]

We want the container view to automatically change its height so all the text will fit. But, if we add 10 lines of text, the "default" result will be:

[image]

So, we give the container view Top/Leading/Trailing constraints of `8` (so we have a little padding on the sides), and a Height constraint of `128`... but we change the `Priority` of the Height constraint to `250 (Low)`. This satisfies IB, but gives us flexibility for its height at run-time.

In our "content VC" we add a label and constrain it Top/Leading/Trailing/Bottom all to `8` (again, just for some padding) and, of course, Number of Lines set to `0`.

Now, in our main VC, we implement `prepare(for segue...)` and disable `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the embedded VC's root view:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    if let childViewController = segue.destination as? MyContentViewController {
        childViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

Now, at run-time, the intrinsic height of our label will increase the height of its superview (the root view), and that will override the container view's Low Priority Height constant, resulting in:

[image]

Here is the complete code for both VCs:

```
import UIKit

class MyContentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add 10 lines of text to the label
        theLabel.text = (1...10).map({ "Line \($0)" }).joined(separator: "\n")

    }

}

class ContainerContentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        if let childViewController = segue.destination as? MyContentViewController {
            childViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Very clear answer thanks so much! They really should make it more obvious that this is what happens.

Comment: After years, still returning to this, best answer on the subject!

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, had an issue with an image being way oversized, this was the root cause. Bravo DonMag!

Comment: Super, but, do note that it's much easier to set it simply inside the child VC!

Comment: Perfect! Worked!

Comment: This worked. It's quite annoying that the value is not honored even when you specify auto layout for the root view of the child view controller in the storyboard. Root views for NIB files seem to preserve which layout is used, so maybe it's a bug? :/

Comment: @funct7 - not entirely sure what you mean... If I'm using Interface Builder / Storyboard, I'm essentially saying *"Hey, UIKit, do most of the layout work for me."* If I want the layout to behave a little differently, I need to write some code.

Comment: @DonMag Sorry about the late reply. For future readers, what I meant is when you're using plain IB, not storyboard, and choose "Layout: Inferred" in the size inspector, auto layout is applied, and you can add it to views without having to call `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. However, when you're using storyboards and do the same for a child VC, that value is not applied and you have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, as you have described in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look into Stack View to see if that suits your needs.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html

Answer (score -1):

To calculate the collective heigth of subviews you can do something like this

```
var width: CGFloat = 0
var height: CGFloat = 0
for view in viewToChange.subviews {
    let wid = view.frame.width
    let hei = view.frame.height
    width += wid
    height += hei
}
print("Sum of your subviews height is \(height), sum of width is \(width)")
```

And change your constraint after